# How to show aggregate counts and percentage together in one table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, counting

What is the easiest way to create an output table that summarizes the count and percentages together? So far I'm only able to write separate queries to pull either total count and percentage, but not able to show both results at the same time.

```
import pandas as pd

d = { 'color': ['RED', 'WHITE', 'RED', 'BLUE', 'BLUE'],
      'count': ['1', '1', '3', '2', '3']}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)

df.color.value_counts()
df.color.value_counts() / len(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have the right idea. One way you can avoid recalculating `value_counts` is via [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html).

```
s = df.color.value_counts()
s_len = s / len(df.index)

res = pd.concat([s, s_len], axis=1)\
        .set_axis(['color', 'pct'], axis=1, inplace=False)

print(res)

       color  pct
BLUE       2  0.4
RED        2  0.4
WHITE      1  0.2
```

Alternatively, you can convert your series to a dataframe first:

```
res = df.color.value_counts().to_frame('color')
res['pct'] = res['color'] / res['color'].sum()

print(res)

       color  pct
BLUE       2  0.4
RED        2  0.4
WHITE      1  0.2
```